# Confusion understanding the term "classic control"?

Tags: control, control-system, terminology

I am trying to study basics of control systems, and I have came across terms like "classic control" and "modern control". These two terms "classic control" and "modern control" are often contrasted.

I have also found a relevant question electronics SE at below link

[What is meaning of "classic" control in context of EE?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/599058/what-is-meaning-of-classic-control-in-context-of-ee)

But after reading answer, still I am confused.

**According to my understanding, here in control systems, "classic" means referring to basic/fundamental level or primary level and "modern" means advanced or secondary** . That is why the answer in above question mentions SISO in "classic control" because SISO are basic/fundamental type of systems

Is my understanding correct or my understanding needs improvement?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_control_theory#Classical_vs_modern

Comment: my idea of "Modern"  uses Fuzzy Logic . Then the next generation will look back and say "modern" means using eavesdropping mic and camera on mobile devices with man-made AI to use control theory on mass marketing. (LOL)

Comment: I interpret 'modern' as state space analysis, regardless of the complexity or simplicity of the system. 'Classical' implies analysis by non-matrix methods.

Comment: In my electronics engineering college, in Brazil (which i dont know if its the same "division" in other places), we stated that modern control is the study of digital and space of states systems. Classical control was LTI systems only, which can be described with laplace transform.